# How to catch data from <form enctype="json">

Tags: jquery, html, json

How can I show in console the data of a form in JSON format with a click function or before submit function?
I'm using this for the form with JSON

```
    <form enctype='application/json'>
  <input name='url[0][namme]' value=''>
  <select name='url[0][type]'>
    <option>Document</option>
    <option>Audio</option>
    <option>Video</option>
  </select>
  <input name='url[0][link]' value=''>   
      <button id="save" class="btn btn-default">Save</button>
       <button id="add" class="btn btn-default">ADD</button>


    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var cont =0;
        $("#save").click(function () {
            $("form").submit(function () {

                return false;
            });

        })
        $("#add").click(function () {
            cont++;
            $("form").append("<br><input name='url["+cont+"][namme]' value=''>  <select name='url["+cont+"][type]'>     <option>Document</option>   <option>Audio</option>      <option>Video</option>  </select>  <input name='url["+cont+"][link]' value=''>");
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: That is not a [valid HTML5 enctype](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-fs-enctype), so what is that supposed to achieve in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

Answer (score 0):

Enctype JSON is not a valid value. So when you set enctype attribute of a form element as "application/json" it is reverted to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" which is default value for enctype attribute. None of browser has implemented the syntax yet that you used.

For more info https://stackoverflow.com/a/38017366/2549901.