# How to BindJSON in Golang

Tags: go

I am passing form data to a controller in Go. I have verified that the data is reaching the controller as its values appear in these variables:

```
emailValue := c.PostForm("email");
passwordValue := c.PostForm("password");
```

However, I am working from a [boilerplate project](https://github.com/Massad/gin-boilerplate/blob/master/README.md) to try to teach myself Go, and I am confused about some further processing included there. The "Invalid signin form" error always gets triggered in the following function:

```
func (ctrl UserController) Signin(c *gin.Context) {
var signinForm forms.SigninForm

if c.BindJSON(&signinForm) != nil {
    c.JSON(406, gin.H{"message": "Invalid signin form", "form": signinForm})
    c.Abort()
    return
}

user, err := userModel.Signin(signinForm)
if err == nil {
    session := sessions.Default(c)
    session.Set("user_id", user.ID)
    session.Set("user_email", user.Email)
    session.Set("user_name", user.Name)
    session.Save()

    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"message": "User signed in", "user": user})
} else {
    c.JSON(406, gin.H{"message": "Invalid signin details", "error": err.Error()})
}

}
```

I can't figure out from reading the docs and other Stack Overflow questions what exactly BindJSON is doing in a case like this. Here is the relevant `struct` in the `forms` file:

```
type SigninForm struct {
    Email    string `form:"email" json:"email" binding:"required,email"`
    Password string `form:"password" json:"password" binding:"required"`
}
```

What is `BindJSON` doing and how do I ensure that `c.BindJSON(&signinForm) == nil`?

Comment: The error that BindJSON returns will probably tell you that the input isn't JSON. Don't just compare it to nil, print it for debugging, and maybe even return it to the client.

Comment: And in case you're not aware, all public Go code is documented on godoc.org: https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.BindJSON

Comment: @Peter Yeah, I've already looked through the godoc.org documentation, it's just that I'm still so early on in learning Go that much of it doesn't really make sense to me.

Even though I use the term "error" in my question, BindJSON isn't returning an error per se. It is returning the JSON object provided in the line `c.JSON(406, gin.H{"message": "Invalid signin form", "form": signinForm})`.

Comment: BindJSON *does* return a value of type `error`: `func (c *Context) BindJSON(obj interface{}) error`.

Comment: It doesn't do that for me. Are you trying to replicate from my code examples?

Comment: I'm not replicating anything. It's just obvious (and not arguable) from the method signature.

Comment: Either it is arguable, or we're not talking about the same thing. I have not seen that error.

Comment: I think perhaps you are meaning that `c.BindJSON(&signinForm) != nil`. Yes, of course that is the case because the `if` conditional is being triggered. I am talking about what the `if` block itself logs. Looking back, my earlier comment should have said that that returned an error, not `BindJSON` itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding here, but if your content is available in `PostForm` calls then I would assume the `Content-Type` is not `application/json` but probably `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  If that is the case, then using `BindJSON` won't work as it is trying to bind the post data to the struct defined by parsing the post data as json.  I **think** this might work:

```
if err := c.ShouldBindWith(&signinForm, binding.Form); err != nil {
   c.JSON(406, gin.H{"message": "Invalid signin form", "form": signinForm})
   c.Abort()
   return
}
```

The alternative would be to actually send your post data as json similar to:

```
{"email": "test@example.com", "password": "pass"}
```

And make sure the `Content-Type` header is `application/json`

I have never used Gin, so this may be completely wrong.

Comment: The first block of code you provided prevents my application from running with the error `undefined: binding in binding.Form`.

Comment: In keeping with the second part of your answer, I'm trying to add `enctype="application/json"` to my `form` HTML element, but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017123/is-form-enctype-appication-json-available) that is not possible.

Where should I define the `Content-Type` header then?

Comment: You would need to import `"github.com/gin-gonic/gin/binding"`

Comment: Thanks @sberry. This is _part_ of the answer. `signinForm` now includes the correct form data. I still need to change something so that this `if` statement isn't being triggered in the first place. The rest of my code, which handles a successful form submission, is inside an `if err == nil` conditional.

Comment: This is the `err` when I log it: `Key: 'SigninForm.Email' Error:Field validation for 'Email' failed on the 'email' tag`.

Comment: Ok, so I've figured out validation with [this](https://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-validation) package. @sberry, can you just help explain to me what `ShouldBindWith` is doing?

Comment: Your response is close enough to the answer I'm looking for, so I am going to accept it and rephrase the question from my previous comment in a new post.