# Submitting form and set content type to application/json in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following form:

```
<form action="/create" method="post" enctype="application/json">
 <input name="some_input" value="true"> 
 <input name="user.name" value="John">
 <input name="user.email" value="john@abc.com">
 <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

When I try to access the input values through the request, I am unable to access the values using the dot syntax as described in the documentation, for example:

```
request()->input('some_input') //true
request()->input('user.*') //null
request()->input('user.name') //null
```

My suspicion is that I am not setting the Content-type to `application/json`, but I am struggling to find information on how to do it correctly in this case.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38017123/is-form-enctype-appication-json-available

Comment: print all the input and check what you are receiving `$request->all()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its PHP behavior to convert `.` into `_`  if exist in post/get request

> Note:
>
> Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For
> example `<input name="a.b" />` becomes `$_REQUEST["a_b"]`.

[Get more details in PHP Doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php#language.variables.external.form)

In Template

```
 <input name="user.email" value="john@abc.com">
```

In Controller

```
 request()->input('user_name') // Will give you john@abc.com
```

To teat it as array use like

```
<input name="user[name]" value="John">
<input name="user[email]" value="john@abc.com">
```

Now you can use `.` in controller

```
request()->input('user.name') // will give John
request()->input('user.email') // will give john@abc.com
```